# How can I get the LED on an iPhone 6 to blink constantly?

Tags: iphone

Sometimes I get caught walking my dog back home in the dark. When that happens, I'd liked to be able to hold my iPhone 6 up and let the LED blink so that I'll be more visible to traffic on our seldom-traveled road. I searched for apps to do this simple thing, but I came up empty. Surely there's a way to get the phone's LED to constantly blink, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what search criteria you're using, but there are countless flashlight/torch apps that offer this function. Usually they refer to an option in their settings for a *Strobe* effect - this flashes the LED.

I've just done a search on the iOS App Store using the term "flash light" and the first three hits offered flashlight apps with a *strobe* option:

- [Flashlight](https://itunes.apple.com/app/flashlight/id451129895?mt=8) by Intellectual Flame Co., Ltd.
- [Flashlight](https://itunes.apple.com/app/flashlight/id455612214?mt=8) by MobileTrends Inc.
- [iTorch Flashlight](https://itunes.apple.com/app/itorch-flashlight-led-torch-light-for-iphone/id384365348?mt=8) by Pixelinlove Ltd

<sup>**NOTE:** I have **not** personally used any of these apps, nor am I affiliated in any way with the developers.</sup>

Comment: I searched for things like "iPhone LED blink." It didn't occur to me to search for "flashlight," because the iPhone has flashlight functionality as part of iOS. Now that I know what to search for, I'll try some of the apps that are available.

Comment: iPhone has a stock flashlight feature built into the phone's software. Swipe up to see your control panel, its on there.

Comment: Right, but the stock flashlight doesn't blink.